# How to handle sending out multiple http request in Node?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, httpwebrequest

I have the standard code for sending out http request.  Using http.globalAgent.

I set my maxSockets be 2500.

And then when I send out multiple requests at once, I get this error:

```
['{'code':'ECONNRESET'}']
```

However, if I sent out the request after a bit of timeout between each request, then it works.

So, questions are:

1) what does ECONNRESET really mean? Why this error happen?

2) How to send out multiple requests instantly without  getting that error?

---

original code to send out multiple requests:

```
// I'm using Seq()
Seq().
 seq(function() {
  this(null, ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5']);
})
.flatten(false)
.parEach(fuctnion(data) {
  // send out request
  sendRemoteRequest(data);  // a function that uses http.request
})
.seq(function(data) {
  console.log("done");
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ECONNRESET` basically means that the remote server has closed the connection. I assume it only allows a certain number of concurrent connections and if that limit is reached it just drops the connection, resulting in a `ECONNRESET` in your program.

Comment: Ok.. so it depends on remote server and nothing I can do about it, right? However in general, what is the best way to handle multiple http requests? because most servers has certain limit, as you pointed out.  So in case of many requests, should I just finish one by one? or any better strategy? :)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the remote server (or firewall/proxy). There is not a lot you can do, except staying below the limit (one by one would be the safest approach). I'd try it with maybe 1-10 concurrent connections and lower that if it fails.

Comment: @stewe I am searching for reason why server drops the connection with ECONNRESET. Does the connection gets dropped at kernel level or is it related to code inside my server application eg. not properly parallelizing the code or doing lengthy read/write on sockets? How can I check/see any logs when connection is dropped on server side.

Comment: is there any follow up of this issue?
Know how to fix it.
but I really want to know who throw this `ECONNRESET` error? os level? or nodejs detect it's about to hit the limit?